# Union of vector subspaces, sum of dimensions of vector subspaces and direct sum of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I am currently reading [*Linear Algebra Done Right*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0387982582) by Sheldon Axler, and I have stumbled upon some proposition that I have trouble verifying.

Excerpt from the book:

> **Proposition.** *Suppose $\boldsymbol V$ is finite dimensional and $U_1,...,U_m$ are
>   subspaces of $\boldsymbol V$ such that: $\boldsymbol V = U_1 + ··· + U_m$*
>
> *and*
>
> $\dim \boldsymbol V  = \dim U_1  +\cdots+ \dim U_m$.
>
> *Then* $\boldsymbol V = U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_m$.

---

So I tried to verify this with an actual example from the book itself that was given in a chapter before.

Say we use these three subspaces:

\begin{align}
U_1 =& \big\{(x,y,0) ∈ F^3 : x,y ∈ F\big\},\\
U_2 =& \big\{(0,0,z) ∈ F^3 : z ∈ F\big\},\\
U_3 =& \big\{(0,y,y) ∈ F^3 : y ∈ F\big\}.
\end{align}

Then:

$\boldsymbol V = U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ (**ok**),

$\dim \boldsymbol V  = \dim U_1  + \dim U_2  + \dim U_3 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3$ (**ok**)

But:

$\boldsymbol V ≠ U_1 ⊕ U_2 ⊕ U_3$ (**not ok**)

---

Could somebody explain me what I am confusing here?

Comment: check the dimension of U1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that $\dim U_1\ne 1$.

In particular,
$$
U_1=\{(x,y,0):x,y\in F\}=\mathrm{span}\,\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\},
$$
and hence
$$
\dim U_1=2.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now :)